# How to sort JS array that puts the words in front in the same order as the original array and the numbers sorted in the back

Tags: javascript

Say I have this array:

```
[ 'say', 'burger', '2000', '1000', '3000', 'full', 'no' ]
```

I want this to result:

```
['say', 'burger', 'full', 'no', '1000', '2000', '3000']
```

Notice the words are all in the front but in the same order as the original array and the numbers in the back sorted. How do I do this?

Comment: Strip the numeric strings out into a different array, sort it, then concatenate.

Comment: Got an example?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far. If you're stumped, the MDN [docs for `Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) are a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

You could check for `NaN` and move this strings to top.

```js
var array = ['say', 'burger', '2000', '1000', '3000', 'full', 'no'];

array.sort((a, b) => isNaN(b) - isNaN(a) || a - b);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Nice solution (+1), but does this sort the "numbers" numerically or lexicographically? OP is perhaps unclear on this point.

Comment: `-` coerces the operands to number.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = ['say', 'burger', '2000', '1000', '3000', 'full', '300', 'no']

//['say', 'burger', 'full', 'no', '1000', '2000','300','3000']

const stringArr = [];
const intArr = []

arr.map(el => {
  if (!isNaN(el))
    intArr.push(el);
  else
    stringArr.push(el)
})




console.log([...stringArr, ...intArr.sort((a, b) => a - b)])
```

Comment: Nice use of rest parameters (+1) but you `intArray` is a string array hence arguably misnamed and would also be sorted so that `"300"` is before `"1000"`, which might be undesired.

Comment: thank you, Nina's  answer is better i am  amazed *-* and there is no `300` it's a `3000`

Comment: I know that `"300"` is not in the array -- but if it was then it would be placed after `"1000"`. In OP's array numerical sorting is the same as lex sorting, but in other cases they can diverge.